# can I call CallNextHookEx in my C# code to send keystroke to my application

Tags: c#, key, hook, keystroke, stroke

I am working on a PowerPoint Plugin and I want to simulate some keyboard keys to make it automatic.
I found a Method to do this

SendKeys.SendWait("{ESC}");

but its not working out. Can I call 
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

But what should use for these parameters. I only know one of the argument that I am sure about : (char)Keys.Escape
what about other arguments ?

Comment: No, you can't use that function, as it's designed to be used when you have a system hook enabled and want to pass the received keystroke to the next hook in the 'chain'

Comment: Which argument should be `(char)Keys.Escape`? I tel you, that none of the parameter should be "ESC". And the main problem, the `CallNextHookEx` function is a special function, that should not be used in this suggested way. You send specific system messages with this function, that your received from system. The function is used, when you need to catch and process specific events.

Comment: what about If I set a hook in my application and then call its callback

Comment: Like:
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOAD_DLL,callback,GetModuleHandle(module.ModuleName), 0);

Comment: and Call that callback
Is it possible